# Discord.js create roles from JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a JSON file containing the following :

```
{
  "name": "Test Server",
  "roles": [
    {
      "name": "Owner",
      "color": "BLUE",
      "position": "5"
    },
    {
      "name": "Co-Owner",
      "color": "RED",
      "position": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Head Administrator",
      "color": "BLUE",
      "position": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using that data, how can I create roles (owner, co owner and head admin) (color and position should be the same as the data for the corresponding role)?

I've already tried this, but all it did was create one "New Role" with no data.

(serverInfo is defined as const serverInfo = require('./file.json'))

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith('!rolecreate')) {
    message.guild.roles.create({
      data: {
        name: serverInfo.roles.name,
        color: serverInfo.roles.color,
        position: serverInfo.roles.position
      }
    })
    .then(role => console.log(`Roles created`))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
})
```

Comment: `serverInfo.roles` is an array, you have to access an index first

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a role using each object, you can use `Array.prototype.forEach()` with the `roles` array.  For instance,

```
serverInfo.roles.forEach(role => {
message.guild.roles.create({
      data: {
        name: role.name,
        color: role.color,
        position: role.position
      }
    })
})
```